# How to trigger Gitlab CI pipeline manually, when in normal conditions, it is triggered by webhook with commit Ids?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-ce

I have Gitlab CI pipeline which is triggered by bitbucket webhook with current and last commit ids. I also want to re-run pipeline manually whenever the build created Gitlab CI file, triggered by webhook is not working as expected. 
I tried RUN-PIPELINE option but shows the error:

The form contains the following error:
No stages/jobs for this pipeline.[image]

Here is the GitLab CI file. Include refers to other project where standard yaml file for the pipeline is kept:

```
include:
- project: Path/to/project
  ref: bb-deployment
  file: /bitbucket-deployment.yaml
variables:
  TILLER_NAMESPACE: <namespace>
  NAMESPACE: testenv
  REPO_REF: testenvbranch
  LastCommitSHA: <commit sha from webhook>
  CurrentCommitSHA: <Current commit she from webhook>
```

Here is the detailed gitlab-ci file that is provided in other project which has stages:

```
stages:
  - pipeline
  - build

variables:
    ORG: test
    APP_NAME: $CI_PROJECT_NAME

before_script:
  - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  - echo "$SSH_PRIIVATE_KEY2" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add -
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
  - echo "$SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS" > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts


Building CI Script:
  stage: pipeline
  image: python:3.6
  only:
    refs:
      - master
  script:
    - |
      curl https://github.com/org/scripts/branch/install.sh | bash -s latest
      source /usr/local/bin/pipeline-variables.sh
      git clone git@bitbucket.org:$ORG/$APP_NAME.git
      cd $APP_NAME
      git checkout $lastCommit
      cp -r env old
      git checkout $bitbucketCommit
      $CMD_DIFF old env
      $CMD_BUILD
      $CMD_INSTALL updatedReposList.yaml deletedReposList.yaml /tmp/test $NAMESPACE $REPO_REF $ORG $APP_NAME $lastCommit $bitbucketCommit
      cat cicd.yaml
      mv cicd.yaml ..

  artifacts:
    paths:
      - cicd.yaml

Deplopying Apps:
  stage: build
  only:
    refs:
      - master
  trigger:
    include:
      artifact: cicd.yaml
      job: Building CI Script
    strategy: depend
```

In the manual trigger, instead of considering the last and current commit she, it should rebuild the application.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for your comment (below), I see you are using the `include` directive (https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/#include) in one `.gitlab-ci.yml` to include a GitLab CI YAML file from another project.

I can duplicate this error (No stages / jobs for this pipeline) by invoking "run pipeline" on project 1 which is configured to include GitLab CI YAML from project 2 when the project 2 GitLab CI YAML is restricted to the `master` branch but I'm running the project on *another* branch.

For example, let's say project 1 is called "stackoverflow-test" and its `.gitlab-ci.yml` is:

```
include:
- project: atsaloli/test
  file: /.gitlab-ci.yml
  ref: mybranch
```

And project 2 is called "test" (in my own namespace, `atsaloli`) and its `.gitlab-ci.yml` is:

```
my_job:
  script: echo hello world
  image: alpine
  only:
    refs:
      - master
```

If I select "Run Pipeline" in the GitLab UI in project 1 on a branch other than "master", I then get the error message "No stages / jobs for this pipeline".

That's because there is no job defined for my non-master branch, and then without any job defined, I don't have any stage defined.

I hope that sheds some light on what's going on with your webhook.

Comment: yes, stage level GitLab-ci.yml file is kept in another project. I have updated my question again with the script in include path.